# Setting up a docker-compose file for ElasticSearch 8.7.0, with autoconfigured security options

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I've tried setting up local ElasticSearch & Kibana services with docker-compose, however, I've run into several issues with the ElasticSearch configuration: the main problem is that I can't get ES to generate an enrollment token out of the box, without setting up SSL certificates myself.

The command ES provides in the documentation works (`docker run --name es01 --net elastic -p 9200:9200 -it docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.7.0`), and this is the behaviour I'm trying to replicate in my compose file as well.

I got into a rabbithole of xpack environment variables that are either incompatible with each other or are deprecated, so I was wondering if someone knows what exactly it is that I need to set in order to have security features be automatically generated by the container.